# How to fix using loopback 4 (translate rest to graphql) : OPTIONS http://localhost:3001/graphql 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: postgresql, vue.js, graphql, loopback, openapi

I am connecting the postgresql with loopback 4 and call the API on frontend using axios + restful and it was sucessfully done.

But when I tried to connect postgresql with loopback 4 and call the API on frontend using axios + graphql, it gives these 3 errors on browser's console:

- OPTIONS http://localhost:3001/graphql 405 (Method Not Allowed)
- Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3001/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
- Error: Network Error
  at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
  at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?b50d:87)

I tried to search and read on googles, but most of them are not using loopback.

I followed this tutorial,

1. https://v4.loopback.io/getting-started-oasgraph.html
2. https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2019/01/query-graphql-api-vuejs-axios/

But still not resolved.

Here is my source code modification, Home.vue.

```
<template>
    <div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from "axios";
    export default {
        name: "HelloWorld",
        async mounted() {
            try {
                var result = await axios({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:3001/graphql",
                    data: {
                        query: `
                            {
                                organizations {
                                  organizationId
                                  organizationName
                                }
                            }
                        `
                    }
                });
                console.log("kk", result);

            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

I expect the output inside console should be the API content. Is there any additional settings which I missed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like the request is denied because of [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

I checked the source code of `oasgraph-cli`, CORS is not allowed by default. Fortunately there is a CLI option to enable support for cross-origin requests.

The following command should fix the problem for you:

```
oasgraph --cors [path to saved OAS]
```

The CLI option is defined [here](https://github.com/strongloop/oasgraph/blob/1f962efd4e8d865bd9a055ab635950b15fbc5adb/packages/oasgraph-cli/src/oasgraph.ts#L26):

```
.option('--cors', 'enable Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)')
```

And applies [the following change](https://github.com/strongloop/oasgraph/blob/1f962efd4e8d865bd9a055ab635950b15fbc5adb/packages/oasgraph-cli/src/oasgraph.ts#L149-L151) to the Express application:

```js
if (program.cors) {
  app.use(cors());
}
```